# Google Play Music "My Library" loses play count when removing tracks

Tags: google-play-music

I've found that if I add tracks to "My Library" using Google Play Music All Access, and play them, I get a play count added to the tracks the same as I would on any other track. However, if I now delete the tracks from my library (but still have access to them as it's *all access*), then I lose the data associated with the tracks - play counts and ratings. This is especially annoying as to force tracks to download to my device I need to add them to my library - it's automatic.

Am I misunderstanding the behaviour of this feature? The situation seems to be that if you ever add a track to your "My Library" (including unknowingly if you elect to download the track) then remove it, you lose the history associated with it.

Comment: That is correct, the metadata is attached to the file.

Comment: Why does the file need to change - either it's downloaded or not, doesn't matter to me as a user.

Comment: Maybe I don't quite understand your concern. But the tracks are no longer in your library, when you play them again it's like you are streaming to check them out. One day you could be adding some files from your local library that match them. Now the question is: should those added tracks be considered new or old? I'd say it's a new copy.

Comment: If you're uploading files it's a different matter. Think about the experience as a *user*. If you download (temporarily) a track, then ever remove it from your library then you lose all history associated with it - this has to be a mistake of design.

Comment: I see what you mean. They should maybe track all that by default and show it. Then have a reset setting for that.